# Paste text stored in VIM buffer with indentation

Tags: vim

I stored the following text in the `"a`-buffer:

```
Alice 
Bob    
Carol
```

I want to paste

```
    Alice 
    Bob    
    Carol
```

To another place. Is there some clever way to do this in VIM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the line above / below where you want to paste has the correct amount of indent, you can use `"a]p` / `"a[p`.

`]p` is "paste and adjust the indent to the current line".

Comment: Wow, much nicer than my solution. +1

Answer (score 3):

there are two ways I can think of to do that:

### way1

after yanking, you could create a line with indentation, for example a leading `tab`, then press `"a]p` the put text would follow your indentation. `:h ]p` for detail.

### way2

If you don't want to "prepare" the indent. Just put/paste as usual, `"ap`, then do

```
`[v`]>
```

Comment: I also use way 2, but without Visual mode: `"ap` and then `>\`]`.

Comment: @glts with `v`, I just wanted to make sure it works for `p and P`

Answer (score 0):

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) now has (among others) `g>p` / `g>P` mappings that paste lines with [count] times 'shiftwidth' indent. This allows it to paste with a certain indent *even when there's not an adjacent line with the same amount*.

#### demo

[image]

Alternatively, the new `g[[p` / `g]]p` mappings are variants of the built-in `g]p` what subtract / add indent, relative to the adjacent line.